# Can one refine an index signature in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

A lib I'm using (Aphrodite) has this type definition:

```
interface StyleDeclaration {
    [key: string]: CSSProperties;
}
```

I want to create a subtype where the `key`s must be a subset of a specified list, but the subtype can be used as a `StyleDeclaration`.

My best attempt has been:

```
type CssTransStyleName =
    'defaultStyle' | 'activeStyle' | 'etcetera'

type CssTransStyleDeclaration = {[K in CssTransStyleName]?: CSSProperties}
```

This works well, up to a point - the point where I attempt to use an instance as a StyleDeclaration.  For example, given:

```
const cssDeclaration: CssTransStyleDeclaration = {
    style: {
        transformOrigin: 'top left',
    },
}
const ss: StyleDeclaration = cssDeclaration
```

the compiler complains that:

```
Type 'CssTransStyleDeclaration' is not assignable 
 to parameter of type 'StyleDeclaration'.
  Property 'defaultStyle' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'CSSProperties | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
```

Apparently, the compiler interprets

`{[K in CssTransStyleName]?: CSSProperties}`

as meaning "every property in `CssTransStyleName` has a value of type `CSSProperties | undefined`, whereas I tried to say that some properties would be present and some not.

Casting `as StyleDeclaration` works, but I'd prefer not to use duct-tape.

---

I also tried

`type CssTransStyleDeclaration = 
    {[K in CssTransStyleName]?: CSSProperties} & StyleDeclaration`

but this makes it effectively the same as simply a `StyleDeclaration`; the properties are not restricted to those in `CssTransStyleName`.

Comment: Could you post the code that creates the error?

Comment: @shambalambala Thanks, updated - see above

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
interface CssTransStyle { 
    defaultStyle: any;
    activeStyle: any;
    etcetera: any;
}

type StyleDeclarationOf<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: CSSProperties;
};

type CssTransStyleDeclaration = StyleDeclarationOf<CssTransStyle> & StyleDeclaration;
```

Here is an example that will help you to understand it:

```
interface CSSProperties {
    someprop: string;
}

interface StyleDeclaration {
    [key: string]: CSSProperties;
}

// This functions only accepts StyleDeclaration
function test(a: StyleDeclaration) {

}

var a: StyleDeclaration = {
    somekey: {
        someprop: "somevalue"
    }
};

test(a); // Works fine because a is StyleDeclaration

interface CssTransStyle { 
    defaultStyle: any;
    activeStyle: any;
    etcetera: any;
}

type StyleDeclarationOf<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: CSSProperties;
};

type CssTransStyleDeclaration = StyleDeclarationOf<CssTransStyle> & StyleDeclaration;

// Works because b is CssTransStyleDeclaration and StyleDeclaration
var b: CssTransStyleDeclaration = {
    defaultStyle: {
        someprop: "somevalue"
    },
    activeStyle: {
        someprop: "somevalue"
    },
    etcetera: {
        someprop: "somevalue"
    }
};

test(b); // Works fine because is CssTransStyleDeclaration and StyleDeclaration

// ERROR c is StyleDeclaration but not CssTransStyleDeclaration
var c: CssTransStyleDeclaration = {
    somekey: {
        someprop: "somevalue"
    }
};

test(c); // Works fine becase c is StyleDeclaration
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to create a type where an instance could contain any subset of its properties.  AFAICT, this solution requires an explicit interface created for each subset used.  For example, if you remove `activeStyle` from `var b...`, the compiler misses it and complains.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't precisely an answer (to my own question) but if I could change the `StyleDeclaration`, I'd change it to

```
type StyleDeclaration<K extends string = string> = {
        [key in K]: CSSProperties;
    }
```

which makes everything work.  The `= string` is a default value for the generic, a new feature in TS 2.3.